# The $out option must be the last pipeline operator

Tags: mongodb

The $out takes the documents returned by the aggregation pipeline and writes them to a specified collection. The $out operator must be the last stage in the pipeline. The $out operator lets the aggregation framework return result sets of any size.
But when i am trying with example getting an error that $out option must be the last pipeline operator though i have written in last of pipeline query .(Throwing EJB Exception-Security violation). If anyone aware of this error. Could you please help me?

Comment: Can you show your Mongodb code?

Comment: could plz tell me reason why this came?

Comment: Only after I look at your code, I will be able to make out something

Comment: <#assign my_pipeline1>
[{"$group":{"_id":{"car_type":"$car_type"},"Total":{"$sum":1}}},{"$out":"collection_name2"}]
</#assign>
<#assign my_pipeline1 = my_pipeline1?eval>
<#assign res=aggregate_collection("collection_name1",my_pipeline1)>

Error:-javax.ejb.EJBException: com.mongodb.CommandFailureException: { "serverUsed" : "live-bo-10:27017" , "ok" : 0.0 , "errmsg" : "$out can only be the final stage in the pipeline" , "code" : 16991}

Comment: @ WBDev; Could you plz tell me exact root cause of error

Comment: Hi Anyone there, could please help to resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

`$out` Writes the resulting documents of the aggregation pipeline to a collection. To use the `$out`  stage, it must be the last stage in the pipeline.
[src](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/)

> Your question is not quite clear, but in my case, I'm using `mongoose 5.13.13` in the `nodesJS` backend, I resolved this by appending the `$out` pipeline as the last stage
> [src](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/5.x/docs/api/aggregate.html#aggregate_Aggregate-append).

```
.append({ $out: "aggr_out_" })
```